# Blender 2.7 models lose their textures in Blender 3.0

Tags: texturing, conversion

I recently downloaded this model to make animations in Blender 3.0 https://www.deviantart.com/jorjimodels/art/Funtime-Freddy-Release-732345375

However upon loading it into Blender 3.0, all of the textures that are meant to be there have been replaced with plain colours, like the eyes.

I then loaded the model into Blender 2.79, and in 2.79 the eye textures load perfectly as intended.

This is what the Blender 3.0 eye 'texture' looks like.

[image: Blender 3.0 Eyes]

And this is what the Blender 2.79 (correct) eye texture looks like.

[image: Blender 2.79 Eyes]

I have searched everywhere for an answer to this question, and I am aware it is an issue with the blender rewrite in 2.8+ but I am yet to find a working solution for this problem.

The model can be found on [google drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1neR95F3xLECB2GENrwZs1eeEjfuQGM2g/view?usp=sharing), note that I **do not** own this model, nor do I claim to.

Comment: Hello, if this is copyright free, please share the file, or at least the eye object? https://pasteall.org/blend/ ... if this is not copyright free, please show the node setup

Comment: @moonboots this model has a no reupload rule, are you talking about the shader nodes for 2.7 or 3.0?

Comment: Yes please show the Shader Editor for 3.0. If it's a free model I guess you can share it? Or at least share on eye (make sure that the image is packed)

Comment: When I turn on nodes for the eyes, it defaults to the Principled BSDF with nothing else, https://i.imgur.com/Xjppozt.png, I will upload the blend file to pasteall for you now

Comment: oh ok so no mystery here why the eye is white, the question is how did it lose its image texture between 2.7 and 3.0, but maybe now show the Shader Editor in 2.7 as well?

Comment: @moonboots you can find the blend file on [google drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1neR95F3xLECB2GENrwZs1eeEjfuQGM2g/view) as it was too big for pasteall.

Comment: @ShadowTheFox please use the [edit] button below your post to add any new information relevant to your question (images, files, etc). There are users that do not bother reading the comments that may have a useful answer, and all information pertaining to your question should be included in the body of the question.

Comment: I can't see anything in 2.7 either, maybe it is using the old Blender Render engine? I don't know enough about it, maybe someone will tell

Comment: Yes, it's using the Blender Internal Engine.  You should remove it from google drives, as that counts as a prohibited reupload. ShadowTheFox has pointed out a script that might do the automatic transition to using material nodes.

Answer (score 0):

**I have found out what the issue is, and have fixed it.**

To fix the issue I had to use [this addon script](https://pasteall.org/7jrP) in Blender 2.79 to convert the model's Blender Internal textures to Blender Cycles materials, and then I could save it and open the file in Blender 3.0 with all materials loaded.

Hope this helps someone else!